# detail page title in browser drops to a backend news detail page title

Tags: typo3, tx-news

It is not a bug, of course, but i cant figure out how to solve it.
With previous version of News there was all fine.
Sorry for my language, it hard to explain.
Current Behavior
For example - I have this page title behaivor for the first time news detail page visit -

**"SiteName: Some NewsRecord Title"** (this is fine, how it should be).

Then when i go to list view, and again click on news to view it in detail (or just refresh the page I'm currently viewing) - page title gets look like this:

**"SiteName: news"** where "**news**" is a page title in the backend page tree, that contains newsDetailView plugin

To override this strange behavior, i use such typoscript setup (But this should not be a permanent solution to the problem, of course)

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 7]

config.noPageTitle = 2
temp.newsTitle = RECORDS
temp.newsTitle {
  dontCheckPid = 1
        tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
        source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        source.intval = 1
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
            field = title
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        wrap = <title>SiteName:&nbsp;|</title>
}
page.headerData.1 >
page.headerData.1 < temp.newsTitle

[global]
```

Environment

```
TYPO3 version(s): [9.5.15]
news version: [8.0.0]
Composer (Composer Mode): [no]
```

Answer (score 0):

With 9.5 and the nice SEO extension you really shouldn't do such stuff anymore. Don't use `config.noPageTitle` and it should work out of the box as the news extension will set the title just right.

Comment: Hi, Georg. May be i was not so clear, but i have SEO ext. installed and activated. But i can not get to right title generation in detail view without using the above typoscript. As i was mention, detail view page title only shown correctly for the first time Detailpage visit. If  i refresh that page than, the title gets like i said above - Site name: backendPageDetailViewTitle.
Clear all caches solves this temporaryly, just until i go to view detail news page and refresh it, or visit for the second time. It is missconfiguration somewhere on my side, i just dont know the way to find it out.

Comment: such stuff helps too, but again, it is wrong way
`[7 in tree.rootLineIds]
config.no_cache = 1
[global]`

Comment: with `config.noPageTitle = 2` you disable the rendering of the title. By using https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html#L21-L32 it should all work out fine.

Comment: The problem is here without using the above TS setup at all (including noPageTitle). Detail Template is fine. It's somehow cache related or something. I can not really figure it out. The title is get correct only once, after the cache cleaning.  On second time detailpage viewed, the news title gets lost. Thanks for attention.